# NextJS 13 application throws Error: Cannot find module './chunks/768.js'

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

After deploying NextJS 13 application in Amazon Amplify, I get following error when accessing the application: It is a simple web application with Amplify social OAuth setup. On local setup the application works without issue. Error appears after deploying my frontend and backend to Amplify.

```
Error: Cannot find module './chunks/768.js'
Require stack:
- /tmp/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js
- /tmp/app/.next/server/pages/_document.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /tmp/app/server.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-    hook.js:23:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.__webpack_require__.f.require (/tmp/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:185:28)
at /tmp/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:103:40
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Function.__webpack_require__.e (/tmp/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:102:67)
at Array.map (<anonymous>) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/tmp/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js',
'/tmp/app/.next/server/pages/_document.js',
'/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
'/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
'/tmp/app/server.js'
]
}
```

1. Tried creating new NextJS application
2. Recreated amplify auth backend
3. Created prod environment of the front & backend application in Amplify
4. Tried with and without custom domain setup

Same error after trying all of above. I will create another nextJS application from scratch tonight and see if it resolves. But any help or suggestions will be helpful.